# How can I open vim with a particular line number at the top?

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I know it is possible to have vim open a file at particular line number using this syntax:

```
vim +500 filename
```

However, I would like it to open with the specified line at the top of the editor window, not in the middle.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could issue `zt` after opening the file, so something like: `vim +500 filename -c 'normal zt'`.

Comment: Thank for the answer.  This one worked best, as the above answer required the user to hit enter once after vim opened.  This opened smoothly to the specified line.

Comment: I thought vim optimized the keyboard layout. This is more complicated then it's worth.

Answer (score 23):

As an alternative (because I ended up here searching for it), if you want to have the syntax `vim <filename>:<linenumber>`, eg `vim test.rb:45`, you can use [vim-fetch](https://github.com/kopischke/vim-fetch) with [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim):

```
Plugin 'kopischke/vim-fetch'
```

Comment: With [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen): `git clone git://github.com/kopischke/vim-fetch.git ~/.vim/bundle/`

Comment: This is the way that Kate open files with line number, Nice.

Answer (score 15):

This should do it:

```
vim +'500|norm! zt' filename
```

Or you could just start the habit of using <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> (top), <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> (center), and <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> (bottom); In my case, it is so automatic, I wouldn't really require the extra invocation argument

Comment: Thank for taking the time to answer.  It is not matter of habit, I am opening vim from another app, and I wanted it to jump nicely to a particular section of specified document.