# VIM: Perform a multi-word command when opening multiple files

Tags: vim, vi, pathogen

My thesis is made up of multiple tex files and I'm constantly flicking between them so I created a shell script, load_files.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

vim file1.tex file2.txt, ..., fileN.tex
```

This works fine but unfortunately because of the complex multi-file structure VIM's spell check doesn't work properly. I found that the answer from @Dominik solved the problem ([Vim spellcheck not always working in .tex file. Check region in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353009/vim-spellcheck-not-always-working-in-tex-file-check-region-in-vim)
). However I don't want to run that command manually everytime I open  the files and I don't want to put it into my tex.vim file because it is only my thesis that has this problem. So I tried to use the -c and the + flag in the shell script but it doesn't work ([Vim - how to run a command immediately when starting vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821033/vim-how-to-run-a-command-immediately-when-starting-vim) and [How can I open vim with a particular line number at the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392424/how-can-i-open-vim-with-a-particular-line-number-at-the-top#10392451)) but it doesn't work. Here's what I've changed the vim line ni the shell script to:

- `vim +"syntax spell toplevel" file1.tex file2.txt, ..., fileN.tex`
- `vim -c "syntax spell toplevel" file1.tex file2.txt, ..., fileN.tex`

They open the files fine but when I turn the spell checker on the problem isn't fixed. FYI, if I open the files normally and run `:syntax spell toplevel` then the spell checker works.

Here is my response to @Conner because it is too  long for a comment:

Thank you @Conner for the help. Are you saying that when I use the `-c` flag the command is only run on the first file and not all the files? This is definitely the problem but the solutions you give aren't able to help.

- I stated in the question that I only wnted this change made to my thesis tex files and so did not want add the command to tex.vim.
- If I create a local vimrc, say `.thesis_vimrc` and use the `-u` flag then if I want my plugins then I need to copy ~/.vimrc to `.thesis_vimrc` and then add `syntax spell toplevel` to it. Unfortunately Pathogen stops working (presumably because it needs all the plugins in that directory but I don't want to have multiple copies of all my plugins). I tried to source `~/.vimrc` within `.thesis_vimrc` with `so ~/.vimrc` but I get the same Pathogen error.
- I tried opening all the files and changing the spelling using `syntax spell toplevel` and then saved a new session using `mksession`. When I open the saved session the `syntax spell toplevel` is not changed.
- Finally I tried to use `modelines` to adding `set modeline` and `set modelines=1` to `~/.vimrc` and add `% vim: syntax spell toplevel` to the first line of the files but then when I open those files, go to the buffers and turn on the spell checker I get the following error:

  syntax=tex
  Error detected while processing modelines:
  line    1:
  E518: Unknown option: toplevel

Surely it can't be this complicated, can anyone help please?

Comment: +1 for using vim to write your thesis! Check out pandoc and markdown if you'd like to have LaTeX options/output without writing in it.

Answer (score 3):

Using `vim -c 'text here'` does work for multi-word commands.

If you read the post you linked to you'll see:

[image]

which instructs you to write the command in your `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` file. This way you don't have to execute it manually.

This can be achieved as simply as typing

```
echo "syntax spell toplevel" >> ~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim
```

If you read `:help -c` you'll notice:

> -c {command}  {command} will be **executed after the first file has been
>               read**

There are a couple of alternative options you have here. If you only want these options for a specific project you could make a custom `.vimrc` such as `.myprojectvimrc` and specify it with `-u`. See `:help -u`.

You could also use vim sessions. See `:help mksession` and `:help -S`.

You could also use a modeline in your files. See `:help modeline`.

As a side note, instead of you using a script for your vim instantiation you could just type `vim file*.tex`.

Comment: A useful plugin for per-project vimrc files: https://github.com/embear/vim-localvimrc

Comment: I'd totally use modeline for this.

Comment: Modelines only support built-in options, not arbitrary Vim commands (like `:syntax spell`), for security reasons. There are plugins that extend modelines in this way, though.

Comment: And with local vimrc plugins, it's not clear whether the command is issued in the correct sequence; i.e. after the tex syntax. So, your first recommendation is spot-on, the alternatives not.